# GOOGLE MAP API v3, Need polygon of a path

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygons

I'm using google maps v3, and my issue is that I have 200+ polygons on one map, they are all editable, and I need to make an ajax call in the event listeners for change which use path instead of the polygon to detect the changes.

so in the callback function this = polygon.getPath(), how can I get the polygon that it belongs to.  In the polygon I use set to set the info I require for the ajax call.

```
    poly1.set('name', 'poly1');
    poly1.set('id', 1);

    google.maps.event.addListener(poly1, 'dragend', setNewArea);
    google.maps.event.addListener(poly1.getPath(), 'insert_at', setNewArea);
    google.maps.event.addListener(poly1.getPath(), 'remove_at', setNewArea);
    google.maps.event.addListener(poly1.getPath(), 'set_at', setNewArea);
```

so in setNewArea, I can easily check this to see if it's the poly or the path, but if it's the path I have no way to get the parent poly for it.  I don't want to have 200 custom callbacks just to hardcode the poly, there has to be an other cleaner way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to add the object reference to poly1 to your assigned callback.  Here is some code I wrote using the maps API that adds a listener for a click event on a specific marker that opens an info window.

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: window.map,
    title: pinName
});

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: content
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.open(window.map, marker);
});
```

So for your example, you might want to do something like what's below.  That will ensure that your callback function is getting a reference to the poly object, even if the triggering event is related to the path.

```
poly1.set('name', 'poly1');
poly1.set('id', 1);

google.maps.event.addListener(poly1, 'dragend', function() { 
    setNewArea(poly1); 
});
google.maps.event.addListener(poly1.getPath(), 'insert_at', function() { 
    setNewArea(poly1); 
});
```

Comment: this was always my plan B, I was just hoping there was a way to get the parent of a path, seems like a normal thing to have and useful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make circular reference among objects.

```
var thePath = poly1.getPath();
thePath.parent = poly1;

google.maps.event.addListener(thePath, 'set_at', function () {
    console.log('My parent is the polygon', this.parent);
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: I attempted this could not get it to work even tried changing it to use set and get and it still did not work.

Comment: don't use getters and setters for this. What happens when you drag a vertex? Does the console.log output something?

Comment: This solved the problem for me. I made a stupid error first, adding the listener to poly1.getPath() instead of the variable I created and set my reference on.